# mod_rewrite sometimes turns off?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess files to make cleaner looking URLs. I have two directories (`subdir1`, `subdir2`) that are folders created inside the root directory. They are not sub-domains. The .htaccess files reside in the three directories: root, `subdir1` and `subdir2`.

The following .htaccess file resides in the root directory:

```
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subdir1|subdir2)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir1/ [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this one is in the `subdir1` directory:

```
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir1/

RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working fine. I can browse the `www.mydomain.com/subdir1/1234-myaritcle.html` page and read its content, but sometimes the rewrite module turns off without creating the clean URLs and the article opens with the following url: `www.mydomain.com/index.php?article=1234`

Can you please help? What is the cause of the problem?
Is there something wrong with the .htaccess files?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your rules is causing the url to appear as `www.mydomain.com/index.php?article=1234`. Whatever link you are opening the article with is probably not generating the clean URLs.

Comment: ummm okay , can some setting on the server prevent the function to create the clean urls ? , cause it works fine most of the time but sometimes the website runs slowly then the links opened as www.mydomain.com/index.php?article=1234 

and i have one more question please 
Dose this effect the way google is dealing with clean-urls? cause i don’t want google to archive the un-clean-urls.